# fetch is undefined at application startup react native

Tags: asynchronous, react-native, fetch-api

I'm using AsyncStorage at the startup of the app, but whenever I start a component that uses `fetch()` at the `componentDidMount()` I got this error `fetch is undefined`, but after restarting the app every thing works fine (error only after the installation of the app).

I found that fetch API is usually polyfilled by react-native at JS startup, but I didn't find a way to fix it.

[image]

**Code**

```
fetch('http://a..e.com/wp-json/wp/v2/offers')
                .then((resp) => resp.json()).then((response) => {
```

Comment: Fetch shouldn't be undefined, it is apart of React Native. It will try to use the global.fetch object, or it'll fallback to the isomorphic-fetch package. Can you show any errors? Is it a case of just `fetch is undefined`?

Comment: @Dan I updated my question

Comment: Are you able to show us the code for your Component where fetch is being called?

Comment: @Dan It's called inside 'componentDidMount()', I don't think that the rest of the code is important for this case ( just rendering the new infos after fetch is successfully called)

Comment: Are you importing `fetch` at all? Unless you show any code I am having a hard time trying to diagnose a problem. I found this Github URL, check the bottom comment (https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push/issues/644).

Comment: @Dan no I'm not, I just want to say that I'm using AsyncStorage in my app component, which is calling this component, the funny thing is after restarting the app the fetch works as expected so I'm suspecting that the initializing of AsyncStorage at the begging (after installation) is causing this error.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that issue, but I already found it and it's not really giving an answer.